# Merge double Attributes with jsoup

Tags: jsoup

Hi i have erroneous html and i want to clean it with jsoup. Some tags have two style attributes. But jsoup just saves only the last one.

for example

```
<body style="color:red" style="font-size:10">
```

Is it possible to concat them?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because Jsoup's parser considers just one occurrence. You have to do something like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String firstAttr = doc.select("body").attr("style");

doc = Jsoup.parse(html.replaceFirst("style=\"" + firstAttr + "\"", ""));
String secondAttr = doc.select("body").attr("style");
```